# convert a list of dictionaries to a single dictionary which has same key names

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which has same key. When I am trying to convert, I am getting only one dictionary as output.

Below is the code I tried

```
d = [{'tk': {'inputCol': 'text', 'outputCol': 'texttk'},
  'sw': {'inputCol': 'texttk', 'outputCol': 'textsw'},
  'hf': {'inputCol': 'textsw','outputCol': 'texthtf','numFeatures': 1024},
  'IDF': {'inputCol': 'texthtf', 'outputCol': 'textidf'}},
 {'tk': {'inputCol': 'domains', 'outputCol': 'domainstk'},
  'sw': {'inputCol': 'domainstk', 'outputCol': 'domainssw'},
  'hf': {'inputCol': 'domainssw','outputCol': 'domainshtf','numFeatures': 1024},
  'IDF': {'inputCol': 'domainshtf', 'outputCol': 'domainsidf'}},
 {'va': {'inputCol': ['textidf', 'domainsidf'],'outputCol': 'assembler_features'},
  'ms': {'inputCol': 'assembler_features','outputCol': 'scaled_features'}}]

out = {k:v for x in d for k,v in x.items()}
print(out)

{'tk': {'inputCol': 'domains', 'outputCol': 'domainstk'},
 'sw': {'inputCol': 'domainstk', 'outputCol': 'domainssw'},
 'hf': {'inputCol': 'domainssw',
  'outputCol': 'domainshtf',
  'numFeatures': 1024},
 'IDF': {'inputCol': 'domainshtf', 'outputCol': 'domainsidf'},
 'va': {'inputCol': ['textidf', 'domainsidf'],
  'outputCol': 'assembler_features'},
 'ms': {'inputCol': 'assembler_features', 'outputCol': 'scaled_features'}}
```

I need the output in the format below

```
 {'tk': {'inputCol': 'text', 'outputCol': 'texttk'},
  'sw': {'inputCol': 'texttk', 'outputCol': 'textsw'},
  'hf': {'inputCol': 'textsw','outputCol': 'texthtf','numFeatures': 1024},
  'IDF': {'inputCol': 'texthtf', 'outputCol': 'textidf'},
  'tk': {'inputCol': 'domains', 'outputCol': 'domainstk'},
  'sw': {'inputCol': 'domainstk', 'outputCol': 'domainssw'},
  'hf': {'inputCol': 'domainssw','outputCol': 'domainshtf','numFeatures': 1024},
  'IDF': {'inputCol': 'domainshtf', 'outputCol': 'domainsidf'},
  'va': {'inputCol': ['textidf', 'domainsidf'],'outputCol': 'assembler_features'},
  'ms': {'inputCol': 'assembler_features','outputCol': 'scaled_features'}}
```

Comment: You cannot repeat keys in a dictionary. In this case what you can do is maintain a list again every key and store your dicts in those lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just impossible to have to identical keys in the same dictionary. One approach you can take is to have the values of the repeated keys in a list, and that list would be the value of that key.

For example, instead having this (which I repeat, is impossible):

```py
{
    'tk': {'inputCol': 'text', 'outputCol': 'texttk'},
    'tk': {'inputCol': 'domains', 'outputCol': 'domainstk'}
}
```

You can have something like this:

```py
{
    'tk': [
        {'inputCol': 'text', 'outputCol': 'texttk'},
        {'inputCol': 'domains', 'outputCol': 'domainstk'}
    ]
}
```

### How can it be done?

```py
out = {}
for x in d:
    for k, v in x.items():
        out_val = out.get(k, [])
        out_val.append(v)
        out[k] = out_val
```

**NOTE**: This will end in a dictionary where all the values are lists (and those with lenght > 1 represents repeated keys).

If you want a clean output where only the repeated keys has list value you can append this to the code:

```py
out = {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in out.items()}
```

Output:

```py
{'IDF': [{'inputCol': 'texthtf', 'outputCol': 'textidf'},
         {'inputCol': 'domainshtf', 'outputCol': 'domainsidf'}],
 'hf': [{'inputCol': 'textsw', 'numFeatures': 1024, 'outputCol': 'texthtf'},
        {'inputCol': 'domainssw',
         'numFeatures': 1024,
         'outputCol': 'domainshtf'}],
 'ms': {'inputCol': 'assembler_features', 'outputCol': 'scaled_features'},
 'sw': [{'inputCol': 'texttk', 'outputCol': 'textsw'},
        {'inputCol': 'domainstk', 'outputCol': 'domainssw'}],
 'tk': [{'inputCol': 'text', 'outputCol': 'texttk'},
        {'inputCol': 'domains', 'outputCol': 'domainstk'}],
 'va': {'inputCol': ['textidf', 'domainsidf'],
        'outputCol': 'assembler_features'}}
```